# Generate 6 Digit unique number

Tags: sql-server

**Edit : It will used as employee unique Number(must be in random order)**

I've a table having column

```
id(auto-increment), uniqueNumber, and some other field
```

for every inserted record i want to generate a 6 digit unique number for uniqueNumber,

Right now im getting this by trigger

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[trgUniqueCode] ON [dbo].[testtable]
FOR INSERT
AS
declare @id int;
DECLARE @Upper INT
DECLARE @Lower INT
declare @result int
select @id=i.id from inserted i;
SET @Lower = 100000 
SET @Upper = (select top 1(isnull(UniqueNumber,999999)) from testtable) 
set @result =(ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0))
update testtable set UniqueNumber = @result where ID=@id
```

Im not sure this method will work, im searching for a best method for generating(priority time execution ), or i'll generate unique number in C# ??

Comment: So, is it C# or SQL server?

Comment: Why not use another sequence? Do you want it to be *random*? Also, why 6 digits? That's pretty small. What happens if you use a number and the transaction is aborted? Is that number able to be reused again?

Comment: @aquinas any example will help

Comment: Random != unique. The cost of *unique* is that it will exponentially rise as you add new rows to the table and have to check the entire set to make sure you haven't generated a duplicate. Can you explain the purpose?

Comment: what about mass inserts with your code. As far as you have got an Identity field, what's the intention?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i dont want to check entire set, and it will used for generating employee unique id

Comment: So what other properties does this unique ID need to have? What is wrong with just using an `IDENTITY` column? Why does it need to be in *random* "order"? If you don't want to check the entire set, I don't know how you're going to ensure that any new random number is unique, unless it is always going to be bigger than the biggest one already in the set.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thats the requirement, i proposed IDENTITY option, but they want it must be in random order, and im making sure is there any way without checking entire set

Comment: Consider this. Throw a bunch of marbles on the floor. Now pick up a red one, a green one, and a blue one, and stuff them in a bag. Now put on a blindfold, and pick up a marble from the floor. How do you know you picked a color that you didn't already pick, without looking in the bag?

Comment: @AaronBertrand + 1 got it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generate a list of all the numbers you *haven't* assigned yet. Shuffle the list and create a new table containing the random ID and an incrementing index. When you need a new ID, select the one with the minimum index; remove it from the unused ID table and return it as your new ID.

Comment: Nice idea. Avoids the problem of increasing computation as more numbers are issued.

Comment: Yep, I was working on this solution too. Well, for what it's worth, here's is how you do it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/962ae/1

Comment: @aquinas Your sqlfiddle doesn't seem to contain anything.

Comment: Great logic, but should have shared the code for it...

Comment: @SabatinoOgnibene this might be one that I intended to flesh out later but forgot about. My SQL is a lot more rusty now than it was then.

Answer (score 3):

Transact-SQL:

```
select floor(rand()*1000000-1)
```

C#:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rslt = rnd.Next(100000, 999999);
```

To generate unique values your best approach is to just increment by one. Other way generating unique value gets more and more computationally inefficient.

Also you might want to go with hash functions, they provide "almost" unique values. But that's the ground I'm not quite familiar.

Third option is to use `GUID`s as unique identifiers. They are quite computationally efficient and guaranteed to be unique even crossing the domain boundaries. However, they are something about 80 symbols, not just 6 :)

Comment: John, a uniqueidentifier is a 128-bit integer not a character string. It is a lot less computationally expensive than a lot of people believe.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a precisely 6 digit long random number from SQL Server using:

```
SELECT CAST((RAND() * (899999) + 100000) as int)
```

I use the following code to update a field in a table with a randomly generated number:

The first piece is a function that is called whenever a new row is inserted into the table.

```
CREATE VIEW ViewRndNum
AS
SELECT CAST((RAND() * (899999) + 100000) as int);


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetID](@Counter int = 0)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RandNumber as int;
    DECLARE @iEmployeeCode as int;
    DECLARE @iExistingEmployeeCode as int;


    IF (@Counter < 20) 
        BEGIN
        SELECT @iEmployeeCode = RndNum
                    FROM ViewRndNum;


        SELECT @iExistingEmployeeCode = EmployeeCode FROM dbo.Employees WHERE EmployeeCode = @iEmployeeCode
        IF @iExistingEmployeeCode = @iEmployeeCode 
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
                SELECT @iEmployeeCode = [dbo].[GetID](@Counter)
            END
        END
    ELSE
        SET @iEmployeeCode = 99999999
RETURN @iEmployeeCode
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeType] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [bigint] NULL,
    [EmployeeCode] [int] NULL,
    [Employee] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastSeen] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Employees_EmployeeCode]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[getID]((0))) FOR [EmployeeCode]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

*Edit*: Oops, missed the "must be random order" requirement. Sorry about that.

In response to that, I suggest a completely different approach to the problem. I think you should push back on the "must be random" business requirement. What's it for?

In my experience it's usually because managers don't want scenarios like "Bob was hired just after Alice, Alice's employee id is 1987 so Bob's must be 1988". My answer to this is "so what?". Knowing Bob's employee ID shouldn't help an attacker - if it does then there are much bigger problems in the organisation's security.

Something to think about and try out while you are implementing the excellent answer above.

*My original, wrong, answer:*

Why not use the auto-increment field?

In SQL Server, create the column as follows.

```
create table dbo.Whatever (
    id int not null identity( 100000, 1 ) ,
    …
```

You should also create either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint to enforce the uniqueness as well as possibly a check constraint to enforce the lower and upper bounds (100000 and 999999, respecitively).

```
create table dbo.Whatever (
    id int not null identity( 100000, 1 ) 
        constraint id_u unique 
        constraint id_bounds check ( id between 100000 and 999999 ) ,
    …
```

Does this absolutely have to be a 6 digit number? Can you use a uniqueidentifier, as suggested elsewhere? The NEWID() function means you don't get serialisation issues of trying to generate a unique number for multiple sessions at the same time.

Comment: i know that, but requirement is it must be in random order

Comment: @SizS What does "in random order" mean? What does the requirement *accomplish*?

Answer (score 1):

I have Created a simple order table in SQL Server 2012 with following code where ODRID is the custom format sales order id.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderTransaction](
[OrderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ODRID]  AS (right('ES00000000'+CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[OrderID]),(11))),
[OrganisationID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SubTotal] [int] NOT NULL,
[Discount] [int] NOT NULL,
[TotalAmount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ModifieddBy] [int] NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderTransaction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = rand.Next(100000, 999999);
```

It's a bit harder in SQL:

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-set-based-random-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
function random_numbers($digits,$id) {
$min = pow(10, $digits - 1);
$max = pow(10, $digits) - 1;
$number = mt_rand($min, $max);
$count = strlen($id);
$ssn_id = substr($number, $count);
$ssn_id = trim($id.$ssn_id);
return $ssn_id;
}

echo random_numbers(9,145);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this--

```
DECLARE @NewPINGenerated Int = CONVERT(numeric(12,0),RAND() * 899999) + 100000
DECLARE @SMS VARCHAR(100)='Message Here '+CAST(@NewPINGenerated as varchar)
```