# Unique code with fixed number of digits

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my mysql database I store offers that can be displayed in my PHP web app. Each offer has its unique auto-increment database ID, which I do not want to show to users. However, I need some public unique identifier.

**Why I do not want to show real ID**

- Number of digits can vary and after some time the number could be too long
- If someone subtracted IDs of two selected offers, he would receive number of offers published between those two offers

**What I want from public ID**

- To be unique
- To have fixed number of digits (optimal 5 or 6)

**What I know**

- Maximal duration of active offer is 6 months (It could be longer in the future, but not more then one year)

**I was thinking about:**

- A singular transformation of "real" ID
- A transformation of timestamp
- Generate list of unused numbers, as it is suggested in: [Generate 6 Digit unique number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349170/generate-6-digit-unique-number)

**Questions:**

1. Is the last option the best for you? Or can you suggest any other commonly used method/technique.
2. Is it OK to keep table with 900 000 rows for all 6 digits numbers?
3. How can I handle situation if (theoretically) my number of active offers exceeds the number of 900 000 (I know that if this happened, point 2 would be irrelevant)
4. Is it correct to have more inactive offers with potentially same ID? For example, it could happen that some user would like to refer to his old offer.
5. Wouldn't be better to use letters together with digits in order to extend the number of possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose your public ID is any 6-character string drawn from a 64-character alphabet (e.g. the 26 letters of the English alphabet, in upper and lower case; the 10 decimal digits of the Hindu-Arabic numeral system; and two further characters e.g. `+` and `/`).

The number of possible IDs that can be expressed in this way is 64<sup>6</sup>, or almost 69 billion.  To put it in context, that's almost 10 IDs for every person on the planet; or one ID every second until the year 4191 CE.  I imagine that you won't exhaust the possibilities before your application is retired or replaced.

So, how can one obtain such a 6-character string?  It's worth noting that Base-64 encoding a 4-byte value, less any padding, will yield 6 characters (although it will only yield 8<sup>4</sup> ≅ 4 billion possible values, as the final character will be drawn from only 4 of the 64 possibilities).

The question then becomes "*what 4-byte value should I use?*"  The suggestions you put forward were:

- > A singular transformation of "real" ID

  A MySQL `INT` is 4-bytes.  If your "*real ID*" is `INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT`, perhaps you could use that:*

  ```sql
  SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '=' FROM TO_BASE64(LPAD(CHAR(id),4,CHAR(0))))
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  ...;

  SELECT *
  FROM   my_table
  WHERE  id = CONV(HEX(FROM_BASE64(CONCAT(?, '=='))),16,10);
  ```

  Note however that you merely have an encoding of the `id` that can easily be decoded: it wouldn't be too hard for anyone else to convert back to a number and defeat the object of this exercise.  One could mitigate against such attacks by [bitwise XOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or)ing the `id` against a known secret, or better yet using a one-way cryptographic hash function.
- > A transformation of timestamp

  A MySQL `TIMESTAMP` is also 4-bytes.  You could similarly use that (just apply [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) in the above examples as appropriate). Note that, if two timestamps are the same (to the second), you will have a collision: you might use the extra 4 bits in the final character to handle such collisions, albeit that only delays the problem to when there are 16 records with the same timestamp).
- > Generate list of unused numbers, as it is suggested in: [Generate 6 Digit unique number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349170/generate-6-digit-unique-number)

  Certainly this is a possibility, but it would be a very large table indeed.  More below.

So, to answer your questions:

1. > Is the last option the best for you? Or can you suggest any other commonly used method/technique.

   It depends on the threat model.  Due to its simplicity, I'd probably go with Base-64 encoding the `id` (possibly XOR'd against a known secret).
2. > Is it OK to keep table with 900 000 rows for all 6 digits numbers?

   Even if it were 6 decimal digits, you'd be talking about more than 900,000 rows (1 million, in fact).  As shown above, by using a larger alphabet than just decimal digits, one has a vastly greater space to consider.

   It isn't clear what you mean by "OK".  If one has the storage space to use, I don't see what the issue would be.  Whilst we are talking about many gigabytes of storage, it's pretty cheap stuff.
3. > How can I handle situation if (theoretically) my number of active offers exceeds the number of 900 000 (I know that if this happened, point 2 would be irrelevant)

   This is why allowing a variable length is handy.  It isn't clear why you object to variable lengths.
4. > Is it correct to have more inactive offers with potentially same ID? For example, it could happen that some user would like to refer to his old offer.

   I wouldn't reuse IDs.
5. > Wouldn't be better to use letters together with digits in order to extend the number of possible combinations?

   Er, yes.  See above.

---

<sup>* Note that the MySQL function Base64 functions were added in v5.6.1; if using an earlier version, you will either need to install a [suitable UDF](https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64), perform the encoding manually—e.g. in a [stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html)—or else conduct it in a higher layer of your application.</sup>

Comment: Probably worth adding that using `TIMESTAMP` would not be very efficient, as it has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` UTC to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'`, so it is already more than half-exhausted.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation and examples, i will use base64 encoding of ID.

Answer (score 1):

Using letters and numbers is probably better, from a usability point of view plus you get more combinations.

Storing a million or so of these isn't going to break much in most scenarios.

Whether to generate these upfront or on demand would be a question of usage - are 1000s of people likely to want to generate a code at the same time? If so, pre-build them. Is storage space a factor? If so consider generating them on the fly.

You should probably avoid having the potential for 2 offer codes to be the same, so either just hook them up to actual offers as they are needed or make sure the generator function generates a unique offer code for each use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best thing you can do is:
1)generate a variable from the date with full parameters (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) and concatenate it with the user email.
Encode this in md5.

2)or use a guid generator like exist in MSSQL servers called NEWID() which is the same thing as c# GUID

and you can substring it from 0 to how many chars you want

I'll not recommende having a list of unused numbers as cause of the performance.

Having it as integer isn't so good also cause it's easier to generate a number from 0 to 9 of 6 chars to hack your database(injections and stuffs like that).