# Restricting access to Excel source data

Tags: excel, superuser

I have an Excel template which reads data from a source Excel file using vlookups and Index/Match functions. I there a way to prevent the end user from accessing the source data file/sheet? e.g. by storing the source file on a remote location and make the vlookups read from there..

Comment: this is better suited for SuperUser, than here.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why you need to restrict access. Is it due to the sensitivity of the data? Are you afraid of the source getting corrupted? More folks will likely point you in the right direction if you can give us details.

Comment: @DaveThornton: yes it's purely due to confidentiality reasons rather than worrying about the corruption of the data. The user will be given, whenever needed, a few user id's then he/she will key in a single user id at a time into the template, the other fields in template will be then automatically populated. The full list of the user ID:s with all corresponding data will be stored in the source data file.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what resources are available to you, it may be difficult to prevent users from just going around the restrictions you put in place. Even if the data is in a database table you will need measures in place to prevent users from querying it outside of your Excel template. I don't know your situation, but ideally there would be someone (i.e. database administrator, infosec, back-end developer) who could help engineer a proper solution.

Having said that, I do believe your idea around using MS SQL Server could be a good way to go. You could create stored procedures instead of using sql queries to limit access. See this link for more details: 
[Managing Permissions with Stored Procedures in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/managing-permissions-with-stored-procedures-in-sql-server)

In addition, I would be worried about users figuring out other user IDs and arbitrarily accessing data. You could implement some sort of protection by having a mapping table so that there's no way to access information with user IDs. The table would be as follows:

- Columns: randomKey, userId, creationDate
- randomKey is just an x digit random number/letter sequence
- creationDateTime is a time stamp and used for timeout purposes

Whenever someone needs a user id you would run a stored procedure that adds a record to the mapping table. You input the user id, the procedure creates a record and returns the key. You provide the user with the key which they enter in your template. A separate stored procedure takes the key and resolves to the user id (using the mapping table) and returns the requested information. These keys expire. Either they can be single use (the procedure deletes the record from the mapping table) or use a timeout (if creationDateTime is more than x hours/days old it will not return data).

For the keys, Mark Ransom shared an interesting solution for creating random IDs for which you could base your logic:
[Generate 6 Digit unique number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349170/generate-6-digit-unique-number)

Sounds like a lot of work, but if there is sensitivity around your data it's worth building a more robust process around it. There's probably a better way to approach this, but I hope it at least gives you food for thought.

Comment: Very interesting ideas.. Thanks Dave for your detailed input, much appreciated. Indeed, sounds like it's going to be a lot of work for this, need to think which approach to take. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Moreover, you absolutely **NEED** these files open to refresh the values in formulas that refer them. When you open a file with external references, their values will be calculated from local cache (which may not be equal to actual remote file contents). When you open the remote files, the values will refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How about if I change the approach: if I save the source data in MS SQL Server and query **only** the values needed for the template, is this possible?